# How can I make my docker containers use my proxy?

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I have two Ubuntu servers.

- Machine A (Internet is heavily restricted)
- Machine B

Also I have one Socks5 tunnel on machine A.

My Socks5 proxy command on machine A:

```
ssh -D 3080 -q -C -N -f root@Machine-B -p 22
```

I want to redirect all traffic through Socks5 proxy.

How can I make my docker containers use my proxy?

```
(Docker Containers) <-> [ Socks5 Proxy on Machine A ] <-> [ Machine B ] <-> (Internet)
```

Comment: You have to set inside each docker container the relevant http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables on the shell to configure proxies there.  some applications don't observe that either so you'd have to do some chaos to make it officially work in those applications' configurations

Comment: How to force all traffic go through ssh tunnel ?